# Work on node.js module in place

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm working on my node.js `demo.location.io` web app at the same time as my `location.io` library. I'd like to be able to make changes to the `location.io` library and push them up to github from inside the node_modules folder. Is there any support for this in npm?

Comment: don't really understand what you're trying to do. you're making changes to your module (location.io?) locally? or is location.io a git server? why can't you just do a git push to github or add a client hook so when you git push to your repo it pushes to github too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(If I understand your question) You can use

```
npm link
```

to link your `location.io` to your local `demo.location.io` repo. More info [here](https://npmjs.org/doc/link.html)